# How to initialise LinkedList<T> with parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections

I know how to initialise `List<T>` using `listOf(elements..)`. But no idea about LinkedList. I couldn't find any article/documentation about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, Kotlin doesn't have a `LinkedList` in the standard library, so there's no built-in way to initialize it either. If you mean `java.util.LinkedList`, you can define a helper function to initialize it, e.g.

```
fun <T> linkedListOf(vararg items: T) = LinkedList<T>().apply { 
    for (i in items) { 
        add(i) 
    }
}
```